# Why does .NET4 try-catch fail on a simple user exception in Release only?

Tags: .net-4.0

Here's an example. On the app below, I click Start, then Stop - in Release only*, the Start routine's catch does not get the Stop's exception.

*EDIT: Now I find this is specific not to Release build, but to any build run outside the debugger. I.e. Release and Debug builds outside the debugger fail, and Debug build inside the debugger is OK. Rather worrying to see that not attatching the debugger can have such a detrimental effect!

EDIT: Here's the stack trace from running Release build from Windows Explorer:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.RunStopException: Exception of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.RunStopException' was thrown.
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Stop_button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Projects\! FastSpecc FAP2\RunStopExceptionfail\Form1.cs:line 35
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

and the stack trace from running Debug from the VS2010 debugger: http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/2749/runstopexceptionfaildeb.png

[image]

Code as text:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Start_button.Enabled = true; Stop_button.Enabled = false;
            }
            private void Start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Text= "Started";
                try
                {
                    Start_button.Enabled = false; Stop_button.Enabled = true;
                    while (true)
                        Application.DoEvents();
                }
                catch (RunStopException)
                {
                    // in Debug build, works fine.
                    // In Release build, fails
                    //  Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. ...
                    //  Exception of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.RunStopException' was thrown.
                    this.Text= "Stopped";
                    Start_button.Enabled = true; Stop_button.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            private void Stop_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Text=  "Stopping";
                throw new RunStopException();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
        public class RunStopException : Exception { }
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't use exception for program flow... are you seeing this when running in the debugger ?

Comment: "are you seeing this when running in the debugger ?" No. And also, I now find I do get it when running the Debug build outside the debugger - note added the question. Thanks.

Comment: please show the stack trace of... A general remark: Looking at the source  I really don't know where to start... you have several there which one should never do - like using Exceptions for program flow, like using DoEvents, like an endless loop etc.

Comment: Yahia, I have added the stack trace to the question. Thanks.

Comment: IF you look closely at the stack trace you see the the even `Stop_button_Click` is outside the `while` loop - thus the exception you are throwing is indeed not handled by your code... I don't see how to fix this code except by rewriting ic ompletely WITHOUT any of the following: DoEvents, endless loop and "exception for program flow"!

Comment: "even Stop_button_Click is outside the while loop" Agreed. And in the debugger it is not (screenshot added to question). So, why the difference?

Comment: Let's stop this discussion... your code is really not anywhere near "usable"... please refactor it as described by me above... within the debugger exception handling works sometimes different depending on the settings in VS...

Comment: I h've found no VS settings that explain this. If anyone else can suggest why this 100% legal code givs such different results in and outside the debugger, I would be grateful to hear. Thanks.